# Enable screen mode (putty)

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm using Putty to control my SSH server, but it's working only if my computer is working and putty is also working. how should i run my server, that it will work even if putty is closed and windows is shutted down also? My friend told me to run server in 'screen' mode but I don't know what exactly it is, so I want you to explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen is a tool for linux to run programs in a 'screen' inside of the system. It is just what you need.

You can install it like this: `sudo apt-get install screen`

You can create a screen with `screen`

By using `screen -list`, you can see all active/started screens.

To reattach to an unused screen, just use `screen (-d) -r [screenID]` > use -d only if screen is still attatched

To deattatch from a screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (release after pressing) and after that <kbd>d</kbd>

A screen runs as long as you don't kill it.

Comment: Here is the answer of Putty, after entering that command:

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for %user%:
%user% is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.